# What do you call a time period between school and college?

Tags: phrase-request

I forgot: when a student takes a year off after graduating from high school before continuing his education by entering a university or something (to travel, for example), what do you call it? There's some phrase I can't remember (maybe, it's from the American tradition or American English), please remind.

Comment: @RonaldSole You should make that an answer.

Comment: @RonaldSole Please try to avoid answering questions in the comment section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term that's used in the UK, and therefore British English, is ***gap year***, but the word has recently entered American English as well. [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=82933749) (*Corpus of Contemporary American English*) shows a bump in the usage of the expression in the last decade.

Attesting to its recency is [this forum thread](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/americas-united-states-of-america/united-states/random-question-what-do-americans-call-a-gap-year) started 13 years ago, where one of the commentators says:

> You could use "gap year" if you're just referring to what it is, but I bet most Americans would have no idea of what you meant. You'd probably have to say: "You know, a year off between high school and college, used to travel/work." Sometimes the term "finiding yourself" is used by older generations, but this has a pretty negative, hippie-like connotation.

Upon googling the term, I found another on Wikipedia, and that is *sabbatical year*.

Now, I have heard this term (particularly *sabbatical* alone) used in reference to a year-long paid leave awarded to professors or researchers at a university. I do not believe this is used for about-to-be students.

---

[The related Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gap_year#United_States) mentions that the practice of taking a year off has indeed become more common in the US:

> In the United States, the practice of taking a "year off" remains the exception, but is gaining in popularity.[26] Parents are starting to encourage their high school graduates to take a gap year to focus on service opportunities.[27] Schools are also beginning to support gap years more; most notably Harvard University and Princeton University, are now encouraging students to take time off, and some have even built gap year-like programs into the curriculum,[28] and many high schools now have counsellors specifically for students interested in taking a gap year.[29]

The references in square brackets link to online news articles and some other (American) websites, which use the term *gap year*.

Comment: I don't think we say *gap year* as often here in the States, but it doesn't sound weird or unfamiliar to me either.  If someone wants to use the term in AmE, I think that'd be fine.